# How to partly merge branches in git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-cherry-pick

I have two branches in my project:

```
master  |    develop 
------  |    -------
abcd    |    bcda7
        |    bcda6
        |    bcda5
        |    bcda4
        |    bcda3
        |    bcda2
        |    bcda1
```

How can I partly merge the branches?
Let's say merge commits `bcda2 - bcda4` to master (I don't need to merge commit bcda1), then merge commits `bcda5-7` to master?

I know how to use git-cherry-pick but I don't wanna use it as it creates new commits and there will be a mess in the future merging the branches. I'd like to retain the current commits ids and just partly merge the branches.

I tried to use

```
git rebase -i
```

I removed lines `pick bcda5 - pick bcda7` therefore It merged the branches but removed commits `bcda5-bcda7` completely.

Could you please advise on how to do that correctly?

Comment: Just du it, it won't create any mess ;)
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486122/how-does-git-merge-after-cherry-pick-work

Greets!

Comment: What is the relationship between commits on the develop branch? Which one is the oldest ancestor, and which one is the most recent? You don't make that very clear in your question.

Comment: bcda1 - is obviously the first, and bcda7 is the recent.